# Searching for records which are added in a specific time frame?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to search for the records in SQL which are added in like two hours? Do I have to include the time in seconds?

Comment: Do you have a `DateTimeEntered` column or some other column to search on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no native support for this.  You'd have to add an inserted date column for each table:

```
alter table YourTable add column insert_time timestamp default current_timestamp
```

then you can:

```
select * from YourTable where insert_time > now() - interval 2 hour
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were to show us your table schema, example data, and what you expect, then we could help you. But from your second question, yes, you will have to include seconds, minutes and hours.

Answer (score 0):

Something similiar to this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE start < '03:00:00' AND end > '05:00:00'
```

or a little more readable:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    `table`
WHERE   CAST('05:00:00' AS time) BETWEEN `start` AND `end`
        OR (NOT CAST('05:00:00' AS time) BETWEEN `end` AND `start` AND `start` > `end`)
```